# Why is the output printing 5 before the heads or tails?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int flip(void); //function prototype

int main(void)// main function{//srand(time(NULL));//random generator

for(int i=1; i<=100; ++i)// for loop flip coin 100 times
{
    
    printf("%2d", flip());
    if(i % 10==0)
    puts("");
    
}// end of for loop 

}// end of main

// Coin flip function
int flip (void){
   int toss = 0;
   toss = rand()%2;
   // generates 1 or 2 at random
   if(toss==1)
       printf("heads");
   else
       printf("tails");
  }//end of flip function
```

Output:

```
heads 5heads 5tails 5tails 5heads 5tails 5tails 5tails 5tails 5tails 5
heads 5heads 5heads 5heads 5heads 5heads 5heads 5tails 5heads 5tails 5
heads 5tails 5tails 5heads 5tails 5tails 5heads 5tails 5tails 5heads 5
heads 5tails 5heads 5tails 5heads 5tails 5heads 5heads 5heads 5tails 5
heads 5heads 5tails 5heads 5heads 5tails 5heads 5heads 5heads 5tails 5
heads 5tails 5tails 5heads 5heads 5heads 5heads 5heads 5heads 5tails 5
tails 5heads 5tails 5tails 5tails 5tails 5tails 5tails 5tails 5tails 5
tails 5heads 5tails 5heads 5tails 5tails 5tails 5heads 5heads 5tails 5
heads 5heads 5tails 5tails 5tails 5tails 5tails 5tails 5heads 5tails 5
tails 5heads 5tails 5heads 5heads 5tails 5tails 5tails 5heads 5heads 5
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), make sure your code appears here exactly as you actually have it, and then ask a clear question in the body itself (not just the title). Before asking, make your best attempt to [diagnose](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [understand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and [isolate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the problem.

Comment: It's _not_ printing '5' _before_ heads or tails.  It's printing that _after_.  You are executing `printf("%2d", flip());` -- presumably the call to `flip()` prints out "heads" or "tails", and then this `printf` call prints out the value that `flip` returned which is 5.  (edit) oh I see your function's "implementation" is actually in one big single-line comment, where indeed we see it prints "heads" or "tails" and then doesn't return any value so you have undefined behavior where the value '5' is probably the return value from `printf` lingering in a register.  Turn on compiler warnings.

Comment: The code shown is inscrutably laid out and is missing the `flip()` function definition.  The code that is commented out contains multiple typos (`elseprintf`, etc).

Comment: `int flip (void)` but you didn't return anything from `flip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call flip and print the result of it. The flip function is printing 'heads' or 'tails', the `printf` is printing the 5

```
printf("%2d", flip());
```

note that

```
int flip (void){
   int toss = 0;
   toss = rand()%2;
   // generates 1 or 2 at random
   if(toss==1)
      printf("heads");
  else
    printf("tails");
}//
```

says that flip returns an integer. (Not sure what the would be) but you do not return anything, what happens is that the compiler is returning to you the last return value of any function, which was `printf` returning the count of characters it printed (Note that is not what should happen, the compiler should warn you that you made an error)

Since its not clear what value flip shoud return I suggest it is changed to 42 - a good number

```
int flip (void){
   int toss = 0;
   toss = rand()%2;
   // generates 1 or 2 at random
   if(toss==1)
       printf("heads");
   else
       printf("tails");
   return 42;
  }//
```

your output will now be 'heds 42tails 42...'

Probably you just dont want to print the result so replace

```
 printf("%2d", flip());
```

with

```
 flip();
```

Answer (score 1):

inside your int flip (void) function , you haven't return any integer , so an integer from the last function return will be considered.  If you print a 5 character string it will return a 5 . if it is a 2 character that you are printing , you will get a 2 .

for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int check (void );
int main(void) { // main function{//srand(time(NULL));//random generator

for(int i=1; i<=100; ++i)// for loop flip coin 100 times
{
    
    printf("%2d", check());
    if(i % 10==0)
    puts("");
    
}// end of for loop 

}// end of main


int check (void ) { 
    printf("hi");
}
```

will print out
something like this

```
hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2
hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2
hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2
hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2
hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2
hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2
hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2
hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2
hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2
hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2hi 2
```

You can change the code something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int flip(void); //function prototype
int main(void) { // main function{//srand(time(NULL));//random generator

for(int i=1; i<=100; ++i)// for loop flip coin 100 times
{
    
    flip();
    if(i % 10==0)
    puts("");
    
}// end of for loop 

}// end of main

// Coin flip function
int flip (void){
    int toss = 0;
    toss = rand()%2; // generates 1 or 2 at random
    if(toss==1)
        printf("heads\n");
    else
        printf("tails\n");
    return 0;
}//end of flip function
```

Answer (score 0):

Flip returns the number of characters printed (5) as heads and tails are same length. And you print the result of flip inside the main loop. So it prints first heads/tails and then 5.
Actually, you should return some meaningful value from flip. Otherwise, flip will return whatever happens to be in its return register.